# The underlying chemical interactions behind torque

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque, physical-chemistry, material-science

I did some searching around, and didn't find any previous topics that address torque in this specific way -- here goes:

Say I just have a plain ol' piece of wood -- relatively long in one axis, so it makes a good lever. That's a substance made up of a series of mostly covalent bonds, without all the wonderful weirdness of metal to worry about.

If I push straight against something with that wood (to NOT use it as a lever), then the force exerted at point of contact with the target is equal to the force I use at the far end, excluding for things like minor compression, fracturing, etc.. It doesn't matter if the wood is 2 feet long or 20 feet long, the force in is the same as the force delivered at the far end.

Now, if I use that piece of wood with a fulcrum to exert torque, suddenly the length becomes incredibly important. A 20-foot moment-arm would be a huge advantage over a 2-foot moment-arm.

So, here's the question:

***How*** is that mechanical difference explained in terms of the way the chemical bonds are strained across the piece of wood? In other words, what's the mechanism that makes the covalent bonds between atoms exert extra force when used with a fulcrum, but NOT when pushing directly?

If it's a change in stoichiometry of the bonds because of potential shearing, does that imply that the torque is exerted because of changes in electron orbitals? In other words, not necessarily the promotion of electrons from one shell to another, but rather a change in the shapes of the orbitals in response to compression -- which still results in a net energy change of the system.

But if that's the case, why doesn't the same thing happen with pulling or pushing on the wood? One would expect the bonds to be stretched or compressed, changing the orbital shapes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wait, you think wood is *simpler* than metal?!?

Comment: In any case, there is no immediate relationship between the bonding details and plain ole mechanical advantage: you can describe the latter just find with a strainable continuum approximation.

Comment: Hah, well, I didn't want to worry about the fermion distribution of electrons in a metal subject to stress, which might vary significantly if we start talking about deformities and all that.

For the purposes of the question, let's just assume that no lever is near the breaking point. Just the simple, basic underlying mechanics of torque as explained by how the chemical bonds react differently from pushing vs. acting as a lever.

Comment: In other words, you want to know how chemical bonds cause the material characteristic quantified by Young's modulus, and whether there is a different cause within chemical bonds for the material characteristic quantified by flexural modulus?